# Loop results PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to fetch all records from my table on my site, I have the following

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != ''");
$sth->execute();

/* Exercise PDOStatement::fetch styles */
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $result) {
    echo $result[First_Name];
}
```

Only its not returning all records, only my first, Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: [Why is $foo\[bar\] wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Comment: check the case of first _name and surname it may also rise a problem

Comment: Just use `fetchAll` instead of `fetch`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you only call `$sth->fetch` once. You need to loop over the results.

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . "\n";
}
```

Also don't call array string indexes without braces. This way PHP checks if the key is a CONSTANT, then casts it to string. This is just bad practice and might lead to unexpected bahavior.

If this returns only one row, you probably have only one row in the database (or the result set). Show us more code!

Comment: This is also only returning 1 recor @vaseliq?

Answer (score 11):

You need to use a loop:

```
while ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $result[First_Name];
    echo ' ' . $result[Surname];
}
```

Or you could use [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method:

```
foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $result) {
    echo $result[First_Name];
    echo ' ' . $result[Surname];
}
```

***And Note:*** If `First_Name` and `Surname` are not constants, then you should use the string as the key name.

`$result['First_Name']` and `$result['Surname']`

Comment: For some reason this only returns 1 record from my table @xdazz

Comment: May be you have only 1 record?

Comment: Or you used the first piece of code that only has the fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) not the fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC).