# PDO fetch one column from table into 1-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm fairly new to PDO and getting them to work with MySQL. I seem to be getting on alright with inserting new data and retriving single results however this I am stuck with.

I have a table that is made up of ingredients, I'm trying to make all the ingredients into a single array.

I've run the query directly into SQL and it shows me all the results, yet with PDO I can not get this with the just a `fetch`. When I use the `fetchAll` approach as below it gives me all the results but in a multidimensional array rather than just an array.

Is there a seperate `fetch` method or do I have to create a loop which adds the results into `$a[]`?

```
$ingredient_q = "SELECT
        `ingredient_name`
         FROM
            `ingredients`
        ";

$ingredient_stmt = $pdo->query($ingredient_q);

$ingredient_stmt ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$a = $ingredient_stmt->fetchAll();
```

Things I've tried:

```
$a = $ingredient_stmt->fetchAll(); // Returns a multidimensional array (not what I want)
$a = $ingredient_stmt->fetch(); // Returns one single result (the first entry)
$a[] = $ingredient_stmt->fetch(); // Returns one single result but in a multidimensional array.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Multidimensional` because you have `multiple` rows or a `single` dimension because you have a `single` row.

Comment: `var_dump($a)` will tell you what you're getting...

Comment: I don't understand, I'm trying to extract all results from a single row, so I assume with that that it would be a single dimension

Comment: Then you, my friend, want `SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE [Please put a condition here]`. This is not at all related to PDO, PHP, or arrays, but your understanding of MySQL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop results PDO PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970771/loop-results-pdo-php)

Comment: If you have multiple rows in ingedients then you will get all rows with that query.

Comment: Now read the new title and think how fatally you can spoil your chance for the proper answer.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `ingredient_name` FROM `ingredients`";
$ingredients = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to `foreach` or `while` through your fetched rows:

```
foreach ($ingredient_stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
var_dump($row);
}

while ($row = $ingredient_stmt->fetch()) {
var_dump($row);
}
```

both are kinda equivalent, `foreach` generates a bigger memory load as you're loading a bigger array, whereas `while` gets one row at a time

notice how to use `fetch` and `fetchAll`; the former is for while, moving through each row one at a time, the latter is targeted to foreach, where the array must be known beforehand