# fetch first column from table

Tags: php, sql, database, class, pdo

First of all thanks for reading this.

I'm having this function setup

```
function SelectHydross($conn){
    $sql = "SELECT * from HydrossTheUnstable"; 
    $data = $conn->query($sql);

    $title = $data->fetchColumn(1);
    echo '<div><table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<th>" . $title['BossName'] . "</th>";
```

Which gives me `Warning: Illegal string offset 'BossName'`

Line 70 is: `echo "<th>" . $title['BossName'] . "</th>";`


If i'm using this code

```
function SelectHydross($conn){
    $sql = "SELECT * from HydrossTheUnstable"; 
    $data = $conn->query($sql);
    $title = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    echo '<div><table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<th>" . $title['BossName'] . "</th>";
```

It does skip the first column and starts with the 2nd.
I don't know any way out at the moment and i'd like to ask for some help!

This is how my table looks like

[image]

Comment: `fetchColumn` gets a single column value. A single column value is not an array.

Comment: we all know how this one's going to end.

Comment: Also fetchColumn(); is a zero based index. So `fetchColumn(2);` would be the `GuildName` column **READ THE MANUAL** Thats what it is there for

Comment: See this Q&A [PDO fetch one column from table into 1-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898565/pdo-fetch-one-column-from-table-into-1-dimensional-array). You could also use a LIMIT with an offset in SELECT.

Comment: You also need to tell us what results you're expecting to get and what should be echo'd.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I want the Name out of "BossName" to be echo'd. Which does work, but with skipping the first column. The echo is my line 70 `echo "<th>" . $title['BossName'] . "</th>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I outlined in comments which I won't repeat (you can read those), you can use LIMIT with an offset that can skip a row.

I.e.: `LIMIT 1,10` in a SELECT statement.

The manual:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Example:

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment, `fetchColumn` targets one row and returns a value, not an array.

Replace this line :

```
$title = $data->fetchColumn(2);
```

with

```
$title = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and your first solution will work.

Edit : If not, maybe you are fetching the results before this line. `PDOStatement::fetch` returns the first line of a rowset, it does not begin on the second one.

Comment: `$title = $data->fetchColumn(1);` to get the `BossMan` column (Zero based index)

Comment: OP: *"If i'm using this code - `$title = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`... It does skip the first column and starts with the 2nd.
I don't know any way out at the moment"* - Um... aren't they using that already?

Comment: Uhm, well i tried both and yet both skip the first column, as you can see in my 2nd code i already tried it. and thank you @RiggsFolly for the hint

Comment: @Max Bit of an update. Just as I suspected from the start as per [my original comment over an hour ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575666/fetch-first-column-from-table#comment68387222_40575666). Just thought you'd like to know. The solution was to use a LIMIT with an offset. That may serve you/someone else sometime ;-)