# how to get one-dimensional array selecting column values

Tags: php, mysql

table `users` - column `nick`:

`SKY
NIGHT
BLACK PAPER
GOLD LINE`

```
$st = $db->query("select nick from users order by nick asc");
$st->execute();
$nicks = $st->fetchAll();
print_r($nicks);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [nick] => BLACK PAPER [0] => BLACK PAPER ) [1] => Array ( [nick] => GOLD LINE [0] => GOLD LINE ) [2] => Array ( [nick] => NIGHT [0] => NIGHT ) [3] => Array ( [nick] => SKY [0] => SKY ))
```

how to get this result:

```
Array("BLACK PAPER","GOLD LINE","NIGHT","SKY");
```

Comment: You could simply reduce the array in PHP

Comment: `Array_column($arr, 0);`

Comment: or even better `$nicks = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO fetch one column from table into 1-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898565/pdo-fetch-one-column-from-table-into-1-dimensional-array)