# I think PDO fetch() and fetchColumn() block each other

Tags: mysql, pdo

So I was experimenting with PDO queries. Take a look at this snippet:

```
1. $rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
2. echo $rows;
3. $row = $stmt->fetch();
4. print_r($row);
```

This is just an observation... not sure how true tho!
Line 2 is executed and returns the number of rows (in my case 1 because I was just authenticating a user).
Line 4 doesn't return anything.

If you flipped the order:

```
1. $row = $stmt->fetch();
2. print_r($row);
3. $rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
4. echo $rows;
```

The array from line 2 is printed but line 4 returns nothing! Is this proper behavior?

Anyways, how do I achieve the following result?

```
if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 1) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    print_r($row);
} else {
    echo '<div class="error-message">Verify Your Credentials</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is proper behavior, fetchColumn fetches one column. You cant fetch it twice. You can use:

```
/* fetches row from the result, if theres no row in the result, fetch returns false */
$row = $stmt->fetch(); 

/* compare if $row is true (in PHP, "boolean value" of unempty array is true) */
if ( $row ) { 
    print_r($row);
} else {
    echo '<div class="error-message">Verify Your Credentials</div>';
}
```

Comment: That was an easy fix! Could you explain what is really going on under the hood?

Comment: @ckwagaba fetching means that the row is taken from the resultset. So when you first called `fetchColumn`, it "takes" the row out of the resultset and then when you tried to call `fetch` afterwards, there are no rows left. I'll also add some comments to the code in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

this answer might help you [PDO fetch one column from table into 1-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898565/pdo-fetch-one-column-from-table-into-1-dimensional-array)

fetchColumn only returns a single result but you can flatten your result in different ways using the pdo::fetch methods, you should look them up and they will quickly and simply sort out your results.  Try this for some more reading also https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes