# Get data from SQL database of multiple columns stored in explode function using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, html

I am using this code to get that data from SQL Server database using PHP

```
<?php   
foreach ($dbDB->query($query) as $row) {

echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['OrderNumber'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Region'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['ShipDate'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['ProducedDate'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>"; } 
        ?>
```

I am trying to replace these multiple lines but storing the columns' names in a string for example **$_POST['SelectedColumns']**.

The values coming into post as comma separated string, For example : Country,OrderNumber,Region,ShipDate,ProducedDate

I have tried this solution but still not working for me.

```
<?php
$ser="********";
$db="******";
$user="******"; 
$pass="******";
$query = 'SELECT '.$_POST['SelectedColumns'].' FROM reporting.REPORT_ALL';

$dbDB = new PDO("odbc:Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;Server=*******;Database=******;Port=1456", $user, $pass);

$row = $_POST["SelectedColumns"];
$rows = explode(",",$row);

/*Here I have the another html code independent of this part */ 

foreach ($dbDB->query($query) as $dataRow) {
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

 foreach ($rows as $r ) {
             echo "<td>" . $dataRow[$r] . "</td>";  }

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>"; } 
?>
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Most likely there is a comma at the end of the string.  Use php's rtrim to remove the last comma. Also you do not need to have a second for each loop as you have already specified the columns to retrieve from the table

Comment: I'd remove your database info IMMEDIATELY.

Comment: @clearshot66 good point, but sadly it doesn't remove it entirely: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45841455/revisions. According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision, JuniorDev will need to ask a moderator to get rid of it completely

Comment: JuniorDev - Firstly what does "not working" mean, exactly? An error? Unexepected behaviour? Secondly I'd be very careful with this. Whitelist the columns you'll accept. Use code to check the resulting query carefully to see that it's acceptable. What you're doing currently is ripe for SQL injection attacks. Never inject POST or GET values directly into the SQL. Read them, check them, then use them to build the query using only strings that _your code_ creates. Use parameterised queries and prepared statements where appropriate, which usually is _always_

Comment: BTW the obvious problem with your existing code, apart from the security vulnerabilities, is that although you `explode` the POST value, you never use the exploded string in your query. You already defined `$query` several lines earlier with the POST _array_ injected directly into it. Just a basic logical error. You need to define $query _after_ the explode command, and use $rows as the variable. But like I said, please don't do this directly - first check the values in $rows first against a whitelist of column names. If they don't conform, don't use them in your query, and return an error.

Comment: Just come back to this. I think I slightly misunderstood your question. You're asking about displaying the data. Your query is still horrendously vulnerable to injection attacks, and you need to write some code to check what the user inputs is acceptable instead of blindly inserting it into your query. But then to display the columns, you don't need explode or anything like that. You can just loop through the columns array as returned by the query. Here's a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12970800/5947043. You can just amend it slightly to output your desired HTML.