# Get data of multiple columns from SQL Server using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the data from SQL Server but only the columns stored in the variable **SelectedColumns**. This variable store the columns' names separated by comma from a drop Down list. For example : `echo $SelectedColumns` will display Country,Product,Date

I could create the header of the table by exploding the variable and use `foreach`. Now I want to get the data of these columns display it in the `<tbody> </tbody>`

Here is my php page :

```
 <?php   
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ser="********";
$db="********"; 
$user="********"; 
$pass="********";
$query = 'SELECT '.$_POST['selectedColumns'].' FROM ********';
$dbDB = new PDO("odbc:Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;Server=********,1456;Database=********;Port=1456", $user, $pass);
?>   

<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>table</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" /> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>                  
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
</head>  

<body>  
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <?php
         $row = $_POST["selectedColumns"];
         $rows = explode(",",$row);
        echo "<tr>";
         foreach ($rows as $r ) {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $r; 
        echo "<td>";                        
        }  
        echo "</tr>";
        ?>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        </tbody>
</table>
 </body>  
</html>  

     <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

I was trying this solution to use `foreach` twice

```
<?php  
$row = $_POST["selectedColumns"];
$rows = explode(",",$row);
foreach ($dbDB->query($query) as $dataRow) {
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($rows as $r ) {
echo "<td>" . $dataRow[$r] . "</td>"; }
echo "</tr>"; 
} 
?>
```

But it's not working. Any suggestions please ? Thank you very much.

Comment: "*..But it's not working.*" So, What's Happening? What Output It's Showing? Any Error?

Comment: @NanaPartykar I receive this error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `print_r($row); print_r($rows);`  Check what output coming.

Comment: @NanaPartykar for example if i select Country,Territory,CustomerName from the drop down list then when i add what you mentioned in the next page i receive this   Country,Territory,Customer NameArray ( [0] => Country [1] => Territory [2] => Customer Name )    then the warning what i mentioned

Comment: It's correct only. But, why it's not showing the desired output. let me check once again.

Comment: This is basically the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841455/get-data-from-sql-database-of-multiple-columns-stored-in-explode-function-using that you asked yesterday.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from SQL database of multiple columns stored in explode function using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841455/get-data-from-sql-database-of-multiple-columns-stored-in-explode-function-using)

Comment: @ADyson i am posting the question other way because I couldn't find solution. I am new to php and also i was checking your previous comments and honestly I didn't know how to change what you mentioned.

Comment: ok but then the solution is to edit your question with more detail, or ask for clarification in the comments. From your history I can see you've posted almost the same question 3 times now. All that does is split people between 3 slightly different descriptions, confuse what the actual issue is, and split the potential expertise that could be focusing on your issue into 3. IMHO you should delete the two later questions and re-focus on the first one. If you edit it, it will go back to the top of the home page for people to look at.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, I didn't know that when you edit the question it will go back to the top of the home page. Thanks for information.

Comment: @ADyson: Today, you are on fire. `:D`

Comment: @NanaPartykar lol I should probably find something better to do :-p

Comment: @NanaPartykar  Any updates please what could be the issue ?

Comment: It looks OK to me. I really don't know what can be the issue. Sorry.